# geomorph readmulti.nts not functioning correctly after update

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

After recently updating R and geomorph, I am getting odd results with the readmulti.nts function.

I used to use the following code to select all my files of a particular landmarked bone. Example code below.

choose nts files:
rawcoords<-readmulti.nts(tk_choose.files())

write out tps files:
writeland.tps(rawcoords, "rawcoords.tps", scale = NULL, specID = TRUE)

If there were 7 landmarks per specimen, I would get a list like this with each specimen and 7 landmarks in a long .tps file.

LM3=7
-2.08968263104371 4.22175118641361 -3.30775562077794
2.69522836895629 4.30375118641362 -2.02281562077794
0.468016368956294 5.97801018641361 -2.71177562077794
-2.53128863104371 2.46923418641361 -3.62374562077794
2.76564636895629 2.45371318641361 -2.25274562077794
0.668037368956293 4.74219518641361 -4.16710562077794
-0.0484946310437069 0.613614986413615 -2.29406562077794
ID=MVZ111760_CC_

...

But now, it splits up each individual landmark to give me a .tps that looks like this:

, , MVZ111760_CC_.nts_1

```
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
```

[1,] -2.645827 6.993647 -8.99664

, , MVZ111760_CC_.nts_2

```
       [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
```

[1,] -0.3037991 6.028037 -9.849427

...

I'm not sure what changed since I last ran this code and I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: I think it could be similar to the issue described here - https://groups.google.com/g/geomorph-r-package/c/1jtqr2cuDVk - but I tried performing the update and did not see a difference.

Comment: And here is what one .nts file would look like

file name: MVZ111760_CC_

inside the nts file:
"Vert6
1 7 3 0 dim=3
2.88916407721918  -1.97797639202044  2.26486934140867
1.42552207721918  -2.84263039202044  2.74336934140867
2.20760507721918  -2.57339639202044  2.46189934140867
2.94546107721918  -1.53152339202044  1.37297934140867
0.637241077219179  -2.65639039202044  2.16489934140867
1.90072507721918  -2.52646739202044  1.53406934140867
1.24879907721918  -1.23329439202044  1.53158934140867

Comment: update: if I load a previous version of geomorph - my code works fine.

Comment: Appending `version[c(4,6:7)]` results and `packageVersion('geomorph')` to the top here will help clarify what version R, and geomorph and help future readers.